# Is it possible to override names of model bound elements with attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As I understandd MVC framework html helpers (TextBoxFor, EditorFor) use reflection for defining the names of input elements to provide reverse binding to the model.
fo
I got used to rather long identifier names for the sake of clarity: `FirstName`, `LastName` and many other examples.

Do standard helpers support any attribute whcih allow abstract from model member names?

For XML serialization we have attributes `XmlElement`, `XmlAttribute` where we can set the name of the element.

Thus I need something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [Name("fn")]
    public string FirtsName {get;set;}

    [Name("ln")]
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and now call to `Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.FirstName)` should give `<input id="fn" name="fn" type="text" value="" />`

Comment: Do the long identifier names actually cause you any problems? Are you worried about the amount of data being transferred?

Comment: Yes, it saves some traffic and potentially (not for TextBoxFor like methods) protects against rename refactorings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do standard helpers support any attribute whcih allow abstract from model member names?

No, they don't. You could write a custom model binder or simply name the properties of the view model as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Do I get it right that modifying model binder is not sufficient and I also need to write my own editor templates?

Comment: If you want to override the `name` attribute of the input field generated by a strongly typed helper such as `TextBoxFor` you need to write a custom such helper. This is something that I have actually never needed to do because I am using view models and the name of the input fields should follow conventions.